# Bootstrap 3 DatetimePicker - Disable list of dates

Tags: bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using Bootstrap 3 date time picker. My requirement is to disable list of dates in bootstrap 3 Calendar.

I am not sure how to proceed. Kindly help.

I am using the below mentioned code.

```
<head>
<!-- ... -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/moment.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" />
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class='col-sm-6'>
<div class="form-group">
<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
<input type='text' class="form-control" placeholder="dd/MM/yyyy"/>
<span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">



var getNextDate = function(){
var date = new Date();
date = date.setDate(date.getDate()+1);
return date;


}

$(function () {
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
format : "DD/MM/YYYY",
minDate :getNextDate()
}).on("dp.change", function (e) {
alert("HI");
});
});
</script>
</div>
</div>

</body>
```

Thanks

Vijay

Comment: You mean only years to be displayed?

Comment: Yogesh, I want a list of dates to be disabled, for example if I have an array containing list of dates ["2014-01-01", "2014-05-06, "2014-08-09"], this array gets generated dynamically when making an AJAX call. I want the dates listed in the array to be disabled in bootstrap calendar. User should not be able to select the listed dates.

Comment: Hi Team - The issue was resovled when I used the below mentioned code -  $('#datetimepickerpopup').datetimepicker({   
 format: "MM/DD/YYYY",      
 minDate: new Date(),
 disabledDates: ["02/24/2015", "02/25/2015", "02/26/2015", "02/27/2015", "02/28/2015"]   
 });

Answer (score 1):

@Veejay - As you mentioned this line works to me as well for DateTimePicker

```
var HolidaysList = ["2017-10-26", "2017-12-25"]
$('#txtdate').datetimepicker({
    maxDate: lastDate,
    minDate: curentDate,
    disabledDates: HolidaysList
});
```